# Ansible não executa comando mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, build

O problema é que em meio a uma automatização de deploy para homologação, tenho que executar o comando `mvn clean install` só que via ansible.

minha task está assim:

```
- name: Build projeto backend
  command:  mvn clean install
  args:
    chdir: "{{ projeto.directory }}{{ projeto.config }}"
```

o conteúdo das variáveis retorna o endereço que normalmente eu executo o `mvn install` e roda normalmente.

O erro que me é apresentado:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "mvn clean install", "msg": "[Errno 2] Arquivo ou diretório inexistente", "rc": 2}
```

Que diacho que arquivo é esse que ele tanto procura?

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza não é a melhor forma de resolver o problema. Mas coloquei o caminho absoluto do maven e funcionou.

Ficando:

```
- name: Build projeto backend
  command: "/home/<USUARIO>/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn --batch-mode install -DskipTests"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ projeto.directory }}master/"
```